How can I save the state of a web application page after reloading the page?
I have an asp net core 3.1 application, the application is very large, I want to save the state of the web page after refreshing the page. For example, the user opened a modal window and after reloading the page, the modal window is already open. I repeat, the modal window is just an example.
I thought about saving the entire page before updating and then loading it, but the problem is that the html changes, and everything else doesn't work, i.e. those scripts where initialization by click is needed, for example.
 $(document).ready(function () { 

     var text = localStorage.getItem('html');

     if (text!= null) { 
            document.body.outerHTML = text;
     }

     window.addEventListener('unload', function (event) {
         const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
         localStorage.setItem('html', html);
     });
 });

What are the ways to track user actions and restore the page state after a reload?

Why do you need to do that? Are you aiming to restore a particular view after a form is submitted, or something? Have you considered using AJAX to send requests to the server, so it doesn't cause a page refresh at all? That's often a good approach, if you have quite a fluid front-end which involves content updates, modals, and so on which are invoked by JavaScript. Of cours it's possible to store some state data before the page is refreshed (or store it on the server after form submission) and then restore the page layout using it, but it's likely to be fiddly and adds a maintainence overhead.

Saving the entire DOM is unlikely to be useful.  But you can certainly save any data you like to localStorage and then use that data when opening the page to set up whatever UI you need to.

local storage, cache storage, session storage, cookies, IndexedDB, there are couple of options you can use on browser side to persist some data. Or service workers caching content of your page and acting as proxy... Many ways

That is, I need my html page to have the same appearance and state of js objects as before the reload, the html view can be saved, yes, but what about objects? For example, I have a global variable in js and it has a value, after refreshing the page this variable should have the same value as before the refresh and I have a lot of objects to save everything at once. I save the html code in local storage, this works.

Do you really need to save everything? Can some things not be derived from others? But yes you can serialize an object to JSON and store it in localstorage. You haven't addressed the comments about why you want to do this though. It feels like there ought to be a better solution to the overall problem. Why are you concerned about page reloads? (Ultimately, on the web, if people refresh a page - which they rarely do in my experience, unless indirectly by posting a form) they'd usually expect that it resets itself.

Saving the entire HTML page isn't a good choice and it will make the error when initializing some event handlers, I suggest you save some relevant state.
For objects, you could also store some objects inside the localstorage,and load it from local storage.
Like below example:
For model popup, we could use localstorage to store the model state when clicking the button.
Then inside the page load, we could use js to check the localstorage's model state and show it.
Codes:
    function showCreate( ) {

                // Show the modal
                $('#createModal').modal('show');

                localStorage.setItem('isModalOpen', 'true');
       
    }

Check model state during page load:
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Check localStorage for modal state
        var modalState = localStorage.getItem('isModalOpen');
        console.log(modalState);
        if (modalState === 'true') {
            $('#createModal').modal('show'); // Open the modal
        }


    });

Result:
It will auto load the model when page opening.


Based on everything that I could find, this is really the best solution. It may be necessary to track some user action and then save it, but there is no way to save the entire html page, since the initialization of objects is lost.

What if, for example, there is a form and when you click a button, the html is dynamically inserted into a div? How can you save this state? That is, you need to emulate a button click? And before that, remember that the button was clicked?

There is no way which could works well for all condition.  When generate the html, it must based on something, for example some data, you could write the js method which receive the data as parameter to load and put the html to the div . Then during the js document.load, you could check the data from the localstorage and call that js method to load the html again.
